# Using hardware clock on linux

Tags: linux, rhel, time

I using an old version of RHEL that I have recently upgraded from 5.4 to 5.8, with a customised 2.30.9 kernel.

The system clock drifts wildly (> 5 seconds/day) unless it is controlled using an external time source such as NTP.

The hardware clock on the BIOS appears to be much more accurate (< 1 second/week).

I have several Linux boxes available, and if I inspect `/etc/adjtime` I find that the drift is measured as 0.000004, -0.000050, 10.000107 and -0.000234 seconds / day on different machines with identical Hardware, OS & Applications.

We need to minimise the clock drift when the externel time source is not available.

I have tried various kernel boot options with varying success to improve things:

Initially kernel set up line in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.9 ro root=LABEL=/ pmtr=0x608 acpi_pm_good clocksource=acpi_pm noapic ide_core.noprobe=1.1 mem=512M ramdisk_size=262144
```

The clocksource files contain:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc acpi_pm jiffies

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
acpi_pm
```

This drifts at more than 5 seconds/day!

First I tried to enable the HPET:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.9 ro root=LABEL=/ pmtr=0x608 acpi_pm_good hpet=enable clocksource=hpet noapic ide_core.noprobe=1.1 mem=512M ramdisk_size=262144
```

The clocksource files contain:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc acpi_pm jiffies

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

This still seems to drift but at only about 4 seconds/day.

Next I tried turning off tsc:
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.9 ro root=LABEL=/ pmtr=0x608 acpi_pm_good notsc divider=10 acpi_pm_good clocksource=acpi_pm noapic ide_core.noprobe=1.1 mem=512M ramdisk_size=262144

The clocksource files contain:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc acpi_pm jiffies

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
acpi_pm
```

This has been running for about a day and there is no noticable drift.

My questions are these:

1) According to this website http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427 the `divider=10 clocksource=acpi_pm` requirement was removed at RHEL 5.3, so why does it improve things for RHEL 5.8?

2) What are the effects of the kernel parameters that I have been changing?

3) How accurate is the drift in `/etc/adjtime`?

4) Is it possible to set up to update `hwclock` when ntp is working?

5) Is there a better way of achieving what I am trying to do?

thanks

Comment: If this is a production server, I'd rather understand what I'm doing before implementing changes. And if you need accuracy, I'd go with a local NTP server.

Comment: If the hardware clock is accurate, can't you just call `hwclock --hctosys` periodically?

Comment: To clarify, is this a happening on a guest machine (a virtual machine)? The link to the VMware KB article makes me thing so, but in the rest of the question, it sounds like its not...

Comment: @derobert No, it's not a VM. I have two servers.

Comment: @schaiba This is not yet a deployed system. I am trying to understand the implications beforehand. The requirement is to minimise drift when NTP (including a local server) is unavailable.

Comment: Actually a clock drift of five seconds per day is *rather good*: One minute par day would be much worse. So I wonder whether all the time put into the effort is worth it: If environment temperature changes by a few degrees, you clock may change speed, too.

Comment: My other advice would be: do *not* use NTP *and* `adjtime` together. Specifically do not use `adjtime` on multi-boot systems: Too many times `adjtime` "kicked off" a rather correct RTC time significantly while trying to "fix" the time in the RTC. Why isn't NTP "good enough" for you?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a different kernel. The custom-made kernel may have some issues with time-keeping.